# BAD_ACCESS during recursive calls in Swift

Tags: swift, recursion

While toying with Swift, I've encountered a situation which crashes and I still not have figured out why.

Let define:

```
class TestClass {

    var iteration: Int = 0

    func tick() -> Void{
        if iteration > 100000 {
            print("Done!")
            return
        }
        iteration++
        tick()
    }
}
```

The `tick()` function calls itself and each time increments `iteration`. Any call of the type

```
let test = TestClass()
test.tick()
```

makes the program crash after a rather small number of recursions (around 50000 on my iMac), with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error: [image: The EXC_BAD_ACCESS]

If I define a similar `struct` instead of a `class`, there is no crash (at least not in these limits). Note that when it crashes, the program uses only a few MB of RAM.

I can't explain yet why this crashes. Does anybody have an explanation? The `callbackStorage` value seem suspicious but I haven't found any pointer on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The runtime error that you are experiencing here is a stack overflow. The fact that you do not experience it when modifying the definition to use a struct does not mean it will not occur. Increase the iteration depth just slightly and you will also be able to achieve the same runtime error with the struct implementation. It will get to this point sooner with the class implementation because of the implicit arguments being passed around.

Comment: `struct`s have indeed the same issue about two times farther. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 11):

In your program, each thread has something called a *stack*.  A stack is a LIFO (last in first out) - a data container that has 2 main operations: *push*, which adds an element to the top of the stack, and *pop*, which removes an item from the top of the stack.

When your program calls a function, it pushes the location of the code that called the function, called the *return address*, (and sometimes some of the function's arguments also), then jumps to that function's code.  (The function's local variables are also stored on the stack.)  When the function returns, it pops the return address off of the stack and jumps to it.

However, the stack has a limited size.  In your example, your function calls itself so many times that there isn't enough room in the stack for all of the return addresses, arguments, and local variables.  This is called a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) (which is where this website got its name from).  The program tries to write past the end of the stack, causing a [segfault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segfault).

The reason why the program doesn't crash when you use a `struct` is likely, [as dans3itz said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30876643/3476191), because classes have more overhead than structs.

Comment: Thanks for the very precise explanation. I was suspecting this kind of issue. Out of curiosity, I've tested the `struct` and the issue occurs indeed about two times farther.
I've attributed the Correct Answer to dans3itz because he responded the first, but your answer is greatly appreciated. Thanks!