# Is my recursive function failing due to a stack overflow? If yes, given my function definition, is it normal?

Tags: ios, swift, recursion

I was testing a recursive function for performance.

In line 33, I create an array with 50,000 items in it; each item in the array is an Int between 1 & 30.

The test crashes when the array has a count approximately > 37500.

I’m not exactly sure what this crash is due to, but my guess is that it’s due to a stack overflow?
Is it in fact due to stackover flow?
Given what I’m doing / this context - is a stack overflow here normal to expect?

[image]

The code is provided below for your convenience:

```
 let arr = (1...50000).map { _ in Int.random(in: 1...30) }

    func getBuildingsWithView(_ buildings: [Int]) -> [Int]? {
        if buildings.isEmpty { return nil }
        let count: Int = buildings.count - 1
        var indices: [Int] = []
        let largest: Int = 0
        var buildings = buildings
        hasView(&buildings, &indices, largest, count)
        return indices
    }

    func hasView(_ buildings: inout [Int], _ indices: inout [Int],  _ largest: Int, _ count: Int) {
        if count > 0 {
            var largest = largest
            if (buildings[count] > largest) {
                largest = buildings[count]
            }
            hasView(&buildings, &indices, largest, count-1)
        }
        if (buildings[count] > largest) {
            indices.append(count)
        }
    }

    func test1() {
        print("-----------------TEST START - RECURSION------------------")
        measure {
            print(getBuildingsWithView(arr)!)
        }
        print("-----------------END------------------")
    }
```

Comment: Does this method produce correct results for a smaller array? If so, then it's probably a stack overflow caused by a too large input array.

Comment: @Sweeper, yes, it does produce correct results for smaller arrays!

Comment: I added details in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a stack overflow, function hasView is called cursively with a depth roughly equal to `count` and the stack has to store `count` adresses which could exceed the stack size for huge numbers.

More details in another post: [BAD_ACCESS during recursive calls in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876288/bad-access-during-recursive-calls-in-swift)

Please note that what you implemented seems to be a running maximum in reverse order returning the indices and this can implemented more efficiently without overflow like this:

```
func runningMax(_ arr: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var max = 0
    var out = [Int]()

    for (i, element) in arr.enumerated().reversed() {
        if element > max {
            max = element
            out.append(i)
        }
    }

    return out.reversed()
}
```

I compared this with your algorithm and the outputs seems to be identical. I also tested with larges values up to 100,000,000 and it is fine.

Returned array does not need to be optional, if the input array is empty so do the output array.

Comment: Side note: stack overflow occurs for a depth of 37,524 in debug mode and for a depth of 130,996 in release mode (speed optimisations).

Comment: I wrote an iterative implementation before I wrote the recursive implementation. One of my recursive implementations was the same as yours. I decided to try the non-tail recursive implementation to avoid having to call the .reversed( ) method at the end.

Comment: Yes that was I pointed out in the first comment: optimisations can improve drastically the results. Also: XCTests normally run with full optimisations. Always profile with optimisation or use the dedicated Xcode profiler (long click on the run button).

Comment: As the overall algorithm is `O(n)` the `O(n)` at the end won't change the overall complexity (but still incurs copy overhead). However you can use `reversed().enumerated()` as you said, plus return a reversed collection instead of an array (you can use `some` keyword to return an opaque collection instead) to get less copy overheads.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211942/discussion-between-louis-lac-and-japsoccer).